# error when trying to install packages with pip install Red Hat

Tags: docker-compose, pip, redhat

Good morning I am trying to install packages with pip install, in this case docker-compose that I want to install it in a Red Hat 8, I already have docker installed, but I have the following error:

```
[dockermd@srvdevrma1 ~]$ sudo pip3 install docker-compose
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try pip3 install --user instead.
Collecting docker-compose
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f324ba08e10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/docker-compose/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f324ba08a20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/docker-compose/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f324ba08cc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/docker-compose/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f324ba084a8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/docker-compose/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f324ba08630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/docker-compose/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement docker-compose (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for docker-compose
```

I already have the proxy configured and everything:

```
[dockermd@srvdevrma1 ~]$ env | grep proxy
https_proxy=https://E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080
http_proxy=http://E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080
```

This happens with any package that you try to install using pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the proxy for the user you `sudo` to. The easiest solution IMO.

```
sudo -i
export http_proxy=https://E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080
export https_proxy=https://E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080
pip3 install docker-compose
exit
```